# Automated testing issue-testng exception

Tags: maven, testng

I have 2 modules both having there respective pom.xmls,I would like to run pom.xml of module1 and using that run some code of module2 by using the classname to be run in the testng.xml.
Now this never works and i get a ClassNotFoundException.
Kindly help.

```
Cannot find class in classpath: com.org.Console1
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:76)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:68)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:54)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:516)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1322)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:170)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:104)
```

This is my testng.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><suite allow-return-values="false" configfailurepolicy="skip" data-provider-thread-count="10" group-by-instances="false" junit="false" name="Suite" parallel="false" preserve-order="true" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" thread-count="5">
<test allow-return-values="false" group-by-instances="false" junit="false" name="Test" preserve-order="true" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false">
    <classes>
    <class name="com.org.Console1">
    </class>

    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>


            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>

                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I think that you will have to give some more information. What are the relations between the two modules? Show the pom files and also the `testng.xml`.

Comment: Still don't see a problem. Can you tell us more about how the two modules interact.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify a suite for just testing. The surefire-plugin has to be configured to catch all your java-classes, the default is to look up for "*Test.java", i personally dont like this behaviour.

pom-snippet:

```
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include><!-- dont just run *Test.java-files, which is default for surefire -->
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Please also verify that your test-classes are in the right position:

src/main/**test**/com/org/Console1.java

It HAS to be there, unless you want to configure it (which i dont recommend)